# Video.js CSS Styling Broken in < IE9 - [A.K.A. Controls Hidden]

Tags: video.js

Having a bit of a conundrum with cross-browser compatibility and could use some help.

Our live version linked to below, seems to work perfectly fine on most browsers, including IE9+, but the controls appear hidden in a non-emulated stock out-of-the-box version of IE8:

http://dig-houston.com/portfolio/inspiron

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like in IE8:
[image: Video.js Controls Hidden in IE8]

At one point, I was still able to slightly see the controls sticking up from the bottom (and click) which lead me to believe something had gone awry in absolute positioning or the rejection of newer CSS techniques. But as my fine tuning progressed and heights were adjusted, I believe the controls were hidden further out of view outside the box.

That being said, I think this is just a CSS issue, but haven't targeted the right styles being applied yet. To anyone else out there using Video.js