# video.js - controls not displaying in IE8

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-8, video.js

I'm implementing videojs and have it working in all browsers however the controls are not visible and the play button is broken in IE8 with Flash fallback.

Following some digging, I've ensured that I'm using the latest versions of js and css by linking to the cdn.

Saw a reference to "boxWidth = box.offsetWidth" but I believe this was corrected since v3.2.

The code is as follows and served up via an iframe in colorbox.js

```
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.0/video.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <?php if (!empty($this->user) && $this->access === true) { ?>        
        <div id="player" class="" style="">
            <video id="video-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay width="640" height="480" datasetup="{}">
                <source src="[VIDEOURL].mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                <source src="[VIDEOURL].ogg" type="video/ogg" />    
            </video>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <script>

        var player = videojs("video-player");
        _V_.options.flash.swf = "[FLASHURL].swf";

    </script>           
</body>
```

Comment: Is it that the icons are broken? There was an update to version 4 (4.0.2) that fixed an IE8 icon issue. It should be in the cdn 4.0 version now. Are you still seeing the issue?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone having the same problem after trying the solutions in this thread, I just went through the same thing and found a fix (for the problem I was having, at least).

VideoJS uses a font called `VideoJS` to represent the control icons.  To display the icons, it uses the font with the CSS3 `:before` selector, **which does not work in IE8 if in IE7 Standards mode**.

Even though you may be using IE8, it's possible the document mode has been set to IE7,  Open up the developer tools, and make sure that you aren't on IE7 mode:

[image: IE document mode]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you looked at the `video-js.css` file, but I hade the exact same problem.

When I inspected `video-js.css`, I noticed that the `@font-face` values for the default skin were pointing to the wrong URL's.

Once I updated these settings to the correct values for where I had installed the font folder (part of the video-js download package), everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
data-setup='{ "controls": true, "autoplay": true, "preload": "auto" }'
```

Try this and remove
 controls autoplay from your code